Multiple data label for bar charts in google sheets
In Google Sheets, I want the bar chart data label to display both value and percentage. Is it possible?
If not, can it be done using AppScript?

Please [edit] your question and insert a table of sample data. Also consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a blank sheet maker that lets you share safely.

One way to do that is to use a formula to copy the data table in a format where the label also includes the percentage.
Assuming that labels are currently in column L2:L and percentages are in column P2:P, use this to create labels that include the percentage in the format it currently shows in the spreadsheet:
=L2 & ": " & to_text(P2)

The new labels will look like Ice cream: 25%.
If you don't have a column for percentages, use another formula to calculate it.
Then add a chart based on the new data table.
See to_text().
